# Why can't post JSON to server in swift?

Tags: json, swift

I able to post the param JSON to server by POSTMAN, but can't post it in this swift code. why?

and my console have this error

> A1AD-41C2-955D-4E000D35C5CC>.<4> finished with error - code: -1002

```
let param = [["cid": "5","accbookname" : "fromiOS2","accbooktype": "test","category": "test","user": "test"]] as [[String : Any]]

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]

    if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])) {
        let serverUrl = "x-cow.com/finnciti/scripts/updateAccountBook.php"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: serverUrl)!,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        print(String(data: postData, encoding: .utf8)!)
        //[{"cid":"5","user":"test","accbooktype":"test","accbookname":"fromiOS2","category":"test"}]
        //can post this on postman

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if error != nil {
                    print("failed!!!\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    //failed!!!unsupported URL
                    return
                }
....
```

[image]

```
[{"cid":"5","user":"test","accbooktype":"test","accbookname":"fromiOS2","category":"test"}]
```

Comment: might you post the JSON used with Postman?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `URL` is not correct.

Try adding `http://` before your `URL` and final `URL` will be:

```
http://x-cow.com/finnciti/scripts/updateAccountBook.php
```

**EDIT:**

I have tested your code with that and it's working. Check below screenshot:

[image]